# Playing third party videos in Brightcove video player

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video-processing, brightcove, video-thumbnails

I have a few videos hosted on a website and I want to play the videos using brightcove video player. The problem is that they allow only videos to play that are hosted on their video cloud because their player code uses the video id (eg. 437622) which is given by their video cloud.

As you can see:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js "></script>
<object id="myExperience1059346274001" class="BrightcoveExperience"> 
<param  name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />   
<param name="width" value="459" />       
<param name="height" value="305" />   
<param name="playerID" value="1044271449001" />            
<param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAA8me3D8E~,Xry9K_L-zJWZ-cMfhF8FDDI0BLyJ9W-6" />
<param name="isVid" value="true" />   <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
<param name="@videoPlayer" value="437622" /> </object>
```

Here this player plays video with id no= 437622 and I want to play video that is
hosted on my own website eg: http://video.abc.com/i-zxvm29QW-640D.mp4  with 
Brightcove video player.

This may help you : http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/best-practices-embedding-video-cloud-media

Is there any way to do so? Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just load an arbitrary file into a Brightcove player on the client side, but you can create a "[remote asset](http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/creating-videos-remote-video-files)" in Video Cloud Studio. This becomes a video with an id, but which uses your file where it is without it being uploaded and transcoded.